# What is "File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module" warning means? How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I am getting this warning '**File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module**'on VS Code when I required Express. What is this mean and how to fix it?
?
[Here is screenshot of the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7VAl.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an existing bug in vscode, you can follow it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47299)

**The only way you can disable this warning is by setting :**

```
 "javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false
```

to your user settings